# using a @min in predicate

Tags: cocoa, nspredicate

My current version for get @min or @max value is:

```
    for (NSManagedObject *destination in allSpecifics)
    {
        [allRates addObject:[destination valueForKey:@"rate"]];
    }

    NSExpression *arrayExpression = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue: allRates];
    NSArray *argumentArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject: arrayExpression];

    NSExpression* expression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"min:" arguments:argumentArray];
    id result = [expression expressionValueWithObject: nil context: nil];

    NSNumber *rateForAdd = result;
```

allSpecific is array of NSManagedObjects.
Looks like is a not good way to fill array of objects before (memory and process time cost). Probably somebody can help refactor it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you have an array (`allSpecifics`) of `NSManagedObjects`, and these objects have a `rate` property?  If that's correct then:

To find the:

- minimum rate value:
  `NSNumber *minimumRate = [allSpecifics valueForKeyPath:@"@min.rate"];`
- maximum rate value:
  `NSNumber *minimumRate = [allSpecifics valueForKeyPath:@"@max.rate"];`
- average rate value:
  `NSNumber *minimumRate = [allSpecifics valueForKeyPath:@"@avg.rate"];`
- summed rate value:
  `NSNumber *minimumRate = [allSpecifics valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.rate"];`

Comment: perfect explanation, thank you for that. its also working well with nsdate